# Access runtime storage `OnEmpty` values from the client

Tags: storage

[StateBackend::storage](https://crates.parity.io/sc_rpc/state/trait.StateBackend.html#tymethod.storage) calls return `None` when the `StorageKey` is empty.

If `OnEmpty` was set, one can decode and parse the `RuntimeMetadata` to access the default value and fall back to it.

- Is there any alternative method to get a storage *default* value from the client?
- In other words, are `OnEmpty` values persisted exclusively on the `RuntimeMetadata`?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to get the storage default value. If you want something like this, you will need to make the default value "shareable" between the node and runtime.

```
struct MyType(u32);

const MY_TYPE_DEFAULT: u32 = 10;

impl Default for MyType {
    fn default() -> Self { Self(MY_TYPE_DEFAULT) }
}
```

Something like this. Then you can also just use `MY_TYPE_DEFAULT` in the node for example.

Comment: It seems you would also be able to access this default value by having the client import the pallet crate, and get it from the storage definition, right?

Comment: Yes, that would also work. I mean, in general importing runtime stuff into the client should be prevented. Substrate is build in the way of having the runtime and client separate. Especially to ensure that the runtime can be upgraded without breaking the client. Here, this would also introduce such a shared "state", but if you force yourself to put the shared item into some different crate. So, you hopefully not break it too easily.